# How to make C# console application variables accessible on the web

Tags: c#, web-services, console-application

I currently have a console application which loops constantly, generating random integer values. I need these variables to be accessible from the web. I have tried to create a web service but I am unable to access these values (I'm guessing since they are two different processes). I have been looking into REST and WCF services but I cannot find exactly what I am looking for. I should say that I am currently using C#

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should take a look into the new ASP.NET Web API

Comment: You can use WCF as described [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9860145/447356) - this is the elegant solution. However, if both the console application and the web site are both on the same machine (or public network) more simple way would be the console application writing to text file in a know location, then the web application reading from that file. If you need any sample code let me know and I'll post it in a new answer.

Comment: I am currently doing this, but there is a lot of disk I/O which I want to eliminate. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Try access the web service from the c# application and not the other way around.
send the numbers to the service and store them in memory or a file...
anyway it will be much more simple than going the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You could host a WCF service in the console application, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms731758.aspx).

Your service contract and implementation could look similar to this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRandomNumberService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int GetRandomNumber();
}

public class RandomNumberService : IRandomNumberService
{
    public int GetRandomNumber()
    {
        return Program.CurrentRandomNumber; // Well ... you get the idea. ;)
    }
}
```